# Auto Open ZIP File Contents After Download

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch file that will be executed by a filewatcher once a zip file is downloaded. After download the file is unzipped with the same name, then the zip file is deleted leaving only the file folder and a single PDF file inside. I just need the command to complete this action for the same file that is unzipped.

```
7z x -oC:\Users\"user"\Downloads\* C:\Users\"user"\Downloads\*.zip

del C:\Users\"user"\Downloads\*.zip

"command opening the file in the unzipped folder"

exit
```

Comment: What application are you using to open the pdf?

Comment: If there's only one PDF file in the directory, couldn't you just `start "" *.pdf`?

Comment: The pdf file is in the extracted folder not on its own

Answer (score 0):

Use **FOR**, if you have multiple zip files, it will iterate over them all.

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Downloads\*.zip") do (
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -aoa "-o%%~dpI" -y -- "%%I"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        del "%%I"
        if exist "%%~dpnI.pdf" start "" "%%~dpnI.pdf"
    )
)
```

This script says, here is the download path. For each PDF in this path, unzip and then delete the zip, open any PDF that was unzipped.

Comment: I substituted my username with "user" in the post and i feel it is causing a lot of confusion. Anywhere "user" shows up the actual value is mdecesare

Comment: Also the pdf is not extracted to the downloads, the zip file is simply unzipped turning it into a file folder with the pdf inside.

Comment: Yes naturally you'll have to adapt any solutions here. %userprofile% will be the value of mdecesare. Then you will need to add a piece of script to determine the foldername that you have not provided to us.

Comment: I rewrote the entire script code to a really working solution (hopefully also for the questioner). The output path on __7-Zip__ command line can be specified as shown in code with `"-o%%~dpI"` or with `-o"%%~dpI"`. Both is supported by `7z.exe`. For help on the used commands run in a command prompt window `del /?`, `for /?`, `if /?` and `start /?`. For help on __7-Zip__ command line double click on file `7-zip.chm` in program files folder of __7-Zip__ and read the referenced help pages below list item __Command Line Version__ on first tab __Contents__.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Start in this dir.
cd /d "%userprofile%\Downloads" || exit /b 1

:: Dir where 7z extracts to.
set "extractdir=unzip_tmp"

:: Zips move here if files or folders exist in cd.
set "faildir=unzip_fail"

rem Continue only if zip files exist.
if not exist *.zip (
    echo No zip files
    exit /b 0
)

for %%A in (*.zip) do (
    set "fail="

    rem Unzip with 7z.
    echo Unzip:  "%%~nxA"
    7z x -o"%extractdir%" "%%~nxA" >nul

    if not errorlevel 1 (
        pushd "%extractdir%" && (

            rem Check if files or folders exist in parent dir.
            for /f "delims=" %%B in ('dir /b') do (
                if exist  "..\%%~B" (
                    echo Exist: "..\%%~B"
                    set "fail=defined"
                )
            )

            rem Open PDF file.
            for /r %%B in (*.pdf) do (
                echo Open:   "%%~nxB"
                start "" /wait "%%~fB"
            )

            rem Move files or folders to parent dir.
            if not defined fail for /f "delims=" %%B in ('dir /b') do (
                echo Move:   "%%~B"
                move "%%~B" .. >nul
            )

            popd
        )

        rem Cleanup.
        if defined fail (
            if not exist "%faildir%" (
                echo Create: "%faildir%"
                md "%faildir%"
            )

            echo Remove: "%extractdir%"
            rd "%extractdir%" /s /q

            echo Move:   "%%~nxA"
            move "%%~nxA" "%faildir%" >nul
        ) else (
            echo Remove: "%%~nxA"
            del "%%~nxA" >nul
        )
    )
)

rem Final cleanup.
if exist "%extractdir%" (
    echo Remove: "%extractdir%"
    rd "%extractdir%" /s /q
)
```

This uses a preset directory to extract the zip files to.
The variable named `extractdir` has the name of the folder to use.
A preset directory allows the ability to search for PDF files in
an isolated path.

The script is quite verbal so can see what is unzipped, moved etc.

Code operation:

- Change directory to `Downloads` directory.
- Exit if no zip files.
- Search for zip file.
- Extract from zip file to `%extractdir%`.
- Check if extracted files and folders exist in parent directory.
  If so, set `fail` to defined.
- Search recursively for PDF files and open them.
- if `fail` is not defined, move files and folders to parent directory.
- Cleanup by deleting zip file or removing `%extractdir%`
  and moving the zip file to `%faildir%` if fail is defined.
- Finally remove `%extractdir%` if exist so it cannot foul up next run.

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to try a fast one liner without dependencies this will depend on the file monitor calling the cmd line (as many can do)

you can add a command to go to a working download directory as required then for example if this page was in the zip as PDF run

```
forfiles /m *.zip /C "cmd /c md @fname && move @fname.zip @fname && cd /d @fname && tar -mxf @fname.zip && start \"\" @fname.pdf"
```

***To delete the zip add  `&& del @fname.zip` onto the end of above before the last `"`***

[image]

There should be little need for error checks as its conditional `&&` so should not overwrite, ***the first abort should be***

> A subdirectory or file *blah blah* already exists.